# Should "have cooked" in the sentence "he could have cooked dinner" be understood as past tense?

Tags: modal-verbs

Consider the following two sentences:

1. He can have cooked dinner (present)
2. He could have cooked dinner (past)

I've been trying to understand how the "have cooked" part should be understood.

Is it in past tense relative to the "can" (present) and "could" (past), i.e. goes before/predates those times, or is it always relative to the present?

Comment: *Cooked* in both cases can be an adjective (formed from vpt), as in "fried chicken". However, in the second case, it can also be a vpt itself. Think again.

Comment: "He can have cooked dinner" doesn't make sense on it's own. It could be part of a sentence such as "I don't see how he can have cooked dinner yet", meaning "I don't think it's possible that that the meal can be ready yet".

Comment: Don't read 'have cooked'. Read 'could have' to mean it was possible to take place in the past.

Comment: Can have done something vs. Can have something done!  Let us compare it with Future Perfect tense; He will have cooked dinner. Replacing WILL with CAN, it is He can have cooked dinner. That way, the usage refers to 'ability/ futurity' too.  He could have cooked dinner, or He could have the dinner cooked, refers to something like 'undone past'.  Hope I haven't confused.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - is this true for both "can have cooked" and "could have cooked"? In both cases, we refer to something in the past relative to now (present)?

Comment: You would have to work hard to build a reason to say _can have_ cooked: "How can it be that he cooked for us when there is no food here?" "Well, he *can have* cooked dinner but packed it for Grandma."

Comment: @YosefBaskin - it's actually pretty common to say that in Danish. But anway, "can have cooked" also refers to the past, just like "could have cooked"?

Answer (score 3):

Of the two sentences given,

> - **He can have cooked dinner*
> - *He could have cooked dinner.*

the first is ungrammatical. Epistemic *can* is a [Negative Polarity Item](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20negative%20polarity), which means that it can only occur in a negative context, like this:

- *He can't have cooked dinner.*

Without the negative in *can't*, though, it's ungrammatical.

So it's not "present" and "past". *Can* and *could* are two different modal auxiliary verbs, with different (though related) meanings, and quite different grammar requirements.

As to the second sentence, the *have* is the mark of the Perfect construction, which is always followed by a past participle of the next verb in the verb chain, as here by *cooked*.

The perfect construction is the only way to get a past time meaning (not "past tense") into a verb phrase that starts with a modal, because modals aren't tensed. Even though your textbook or teacher might tell you, they're talking about Middle English; Modern English modal auxiliary verbs are untensed. So you can't say, about the past:

- **I musted go yesterday* (you say *I had to go yesterday* instead)
- **He coulded cook dinner* (you say *He could have cooked dinner*)

How [modals](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20modal%20auxiliary%20verbs) interact with perfect varies:

- **can have* is ungrammatical, but not *could have*
- *will have* and *would have* are both fine but mean different things
- **shall have* is ungrammatical, but *should have* is fine
- *may have* and *might have* are essentially identical in meaning.

Comment: "He can't have cooked the dinner" may be negative polarity but it's definitely past in meaning, which should be pointed out to a learner.

Comment: True. It's an epistemic, so it means that it's impossible that he cooked the dinner (in the opinion of the speaker).

Comment: I wonder if epistemic modality allows for 100% certainty. "He can't have done it." sounds pretty certain to me (90%-100%). "He didn't do it," is more of a statement of fact (also in the opinion of the speaker). But "he didn't do it" is not an epistemic, is it? (no modal verbs)

Comment: This can't have translates to: It is not possible that he did it. It is certainty of "it is not possible that [verb in the past]".

Comment: As Robin Lakoff once pointed out, using **any** modal is less certain than simple assertion. _He did it_ is much more certain than _He must have done it_; _He didn't do it_ is more certain than _He couldn't have done it_. Use of the modal marks speaker's judgement rather than more objective certainty.